# Can I tell who approved merge requests?

Tags: gitlab

I have GitLab Starter which seems to mean that I am unable to restrict code approvers on a directory basis as everyone needs developer level access.

This is causing slight headaches.

Is there a way in GitLab that I can review who approved groups of merge requests?  This way I can at least check after the fact that no one has approved code who should not have.

Is there a way to query the backend database or a way of gaining this information in some GUI screen somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a way, with [the upcoming GitLab 13.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62519567/6309) to clearly see the status of the approval process and who has approved a MR.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/blogimages/reviewers_sidebar.png]

In the meantime, you still have the [GitLab Merge Request approval API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html) and the [merge request API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests), with a call like `GET /merge_requests` does include paramters like `approver_ids`

> Returns merge requests which have specified all the users with the given ids as individual approvers.
>
> - `None` returns merge requests without approvers.
> - `Any` returns merge requests with an approver.

That could help checking who has approved a MR.

> Users on GitLab Starter, Bronze, or higher will also see the `approvals_before_merge` parameter.